# Given a sentence, how can I generate similar sentences of that particular sentence using machine learning or other ways?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, sentence-similarity

I am testing my AI app that ask a question and based on that do some processing. I have to write some tests that even people ask the same question in different way the system will generate same result.

Now let's say question is as below

Who is a Software Manager?

Now someone can also ask Who is a Software Development Manager. or who is Software lead or who is Application Manager.

Can I generate multiple test cases like these to give one base question and it can generate multiple permutations of the same question?

I didn't try anything and need some guidance

Answer (score -2):

This might be something that ChatGPT can help with. Give it your base sentence and then ask it for similar sentences/sentences with the same meaning.

You will probably have to vet the results, but the alternative is to develop these sentences yourself.